# show that $n + \lfloor \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2}\rfloor$ is never a perfect square for all positive integers $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

show that $n + \lfloor \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2}\rfloor$ is never a perfect square for all positive integers $n$

I am thinking of a proof by contradiction by assuming $n + \lfloor \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2}\rfloor = k^2 \implies \lfloor \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2}\rfloor  = k^2-n $

Comment: sorry there is a typo let me fix it quick

Comment: kindly check now

Comment: Alex, if $n = 6$ then $n + \lfloor\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor = 6 + \lfloor 2.949\ldots\rfloor = 8$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: Yes! I have deleted my comment.

Comment: Consider $4(n+ \lfloor \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor)$ and try to show that this lies between two consecutive squares.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $t=\lfloor\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor$, so $t-\frac{1}{2}\le\sqrt{n}<t+\frac{1}{2}$.

If $n+t=k^2$ for some integer $k$,

then $t^2-t+\frac{1}{4}\le n<t^2+t+\frac{1}{4}\implies t^2+\frac{1}{4}\le n+t<t^2+2t+\frac{1}{4}<(t+1)^2\implies$

$t^2<k^2<(t+1)^2$, which gives a contradiction.